# An exception occurred executing JS interop: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]. Path: $[0].tGorderid

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I had used blazorIndexedDb package for blazorWASM application

Public class Orders
{
Public long? TGorderid

---remaing proprties---
}

```
 orders = (await manager.ToArray<Orders>("Orders")).ToList();
```

An exception occurred executing JS interop: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]. Path: $[0].tGorderid | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 110..

How to fix this issue exctly when reterive the orders

PLease help me. Thansks

An exception occurred executing JS interop: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]. Path: $[0].tGorderid | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 110..